# Find $x$-coordinates of intersection points of $\sin x$ and $\sin 2x$

Tags: calculus

In solving this, why can't I just use
Taking inverse of both sides, 
$$\arcsin x = \arcsin 2x$$

I know the other method i.e expanding $\sin 2x = 2\sin x\cos x$.

Please explain why I can't use inverse method

Comment: And what do you do after $\arcsin x=\arcsin2x$?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the other method, $$\sin(\theta)=x\quad\text{does not imply}\quad \theta=\arcsin(x)$$

The above is only valid for $-\frac{\pi}{2}\le \theta\le \frac{\pi}{2}$